# Parse all column elements from a linux bash command output

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to parse the column elements of the output from the command `lsscsi`.

Here is a sample output,

```
# lsscsi

[0:0:0:0]   disk   ATA   VBOX HARDDISK   1.0   /dev/sda
[0:0:1:0]   disk   ATA   VBOX HARDDISK   1.0   /dev/sdb
[1:0:1:0]   disk   ATA   VBOX HARDDISK   1.0   /dev/sdc
```

Example if I want column 2, my output should be,

```
disk
disk
disk
```

If column 7,

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
```

Comment: For what purpose?  See `man awk`, or `man cut` for a starting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the [awk](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) utility could be your friend

```
lsscsi | awk '{print $7}'
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc

lsscsi | awk '{print $2}'
disk
disk
disk
```

or you could use [cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) but you may need to mess about with the spaces first

```
lsscsi | sed 's/ \+/ /g' | cut -f7 -d' '
```